# What is the density of numbers which have at least two divisors whose sum is a perfect square?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, asymptotics, divisibility, analytic-number-theory

**Update**: [Posted in MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/442684/what-is-the-density-of-numbers-which-have-at-least-two-divisors-whose-sum-is-a-p) since it is unanswered in MSE after 2 years.

*A positive integer is said to have square-sum divisors if it has at least two divisors whose sum is a perfect square.*

- $6$ has square-sum divisors because its divisors are $(1,2,3,6)$ and $1 + 3 = 2^2$. Also $3 + 6 = 3^2$
- $10$ has no square-sum divisors since no two of its divisors $(1,2,5,10)$ add up to a square

Trivially, all multiples of $3, 8, 14, 20, 34, 35, 46, 55, 62, 94, 95, 130, 142, 143, 155, 158, ...$ have square-sum divisors.

**Question**: Let $f(n)$ be the number of positive integers $\le n$ which have square-sum divisors. What is the limiting value

$$
\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{f(n)}{n}
$$

**Update 14-Jun-2021**: For $n = 1.3 \times 10^{10}$, the ratio is $0.571284$ showing that the growth rate is extremely slow since the ratio had reached $0.57$ by $n = 4 \times 10^5$.

**Sagemath code** using extended skip list suggested by Mees de Vries.

```
n = f = 0
step = 10^5
target = f

skip = [3, 8, 14, 20, 34, 35, 46, 55, 62, 94, 95, 130, 142, 143, 155, 158,
        194, 203, 254, 295, 299, 323, 334, 395, 398, 418, 430, 446, 473, 482]

while n < 10^30:
    d = divisors(n)
    l = len(d)
    c = i = 0
    stop = False
    
    while i < l and stop == False:
        j = i + 1
        while j < l and stop == False:
            if (d[i] + d[j])^0.5 %1 == 0:
                c = 1
                stop = True
            j = j + 1
        i = i + 1
        
    if c == 0:
        f = f + 1 
        
    if f >= target:
        print(f,n,1 - f/n.n())
        target = target + step

    found = False
    while found == False:
        n = n + 1
        if all(n%x != 0 for x in skip):
            found = True
```

Comment: What is the reason for this conjecture? Numerical evidence?

Comment: With a quick script: your value reaches $0.570...$ by $n = 400,000$, and apparently continues to increase. However, at $n = 25,000,000$ it still "only" equals $0.5710...$ (compared to $\gamma = 0.57721...$).

Comment: @MeesdeVries Yes this is based on numerical data.  At $n = 150,000,000$, it reaches $0.5711$ and is growing but at a very very slow rate. I have added my script to the post. Can you share yours, wanted to see if I can make it faster.

Comment: My script just reached $2.5 \times 10^8$, and your value is at $0.57118\ldots$ (although that last digit might turn into a 9 in the foreseeable future). Here is my script (sympy for divisors, run with Pypy, not optimized): https://pastebin.com/sVx8t3N2

Comment: At $3.5 \times 10^8$, your value is at $0.57119980857\ldots$, although it has passed $0.571200\ldots$ a few times before that. (This will be my last numerical update, but I have this question bookmarked -- looking forward to any concrete answers.)

Comment: I note that the numbers in question can be represented in the form $jk(n^2-j)$

Comment: Interesting question (+1). The downvote is incomprehensible. I see little hope to actually determine the limit, I am sceptical that it is actually the Euler-Mascheroni constant, but this would in fact be a very nice result.

Comment: @Peter This is not a nice question. When counting the number of such pairs of divisors we get $\sum_{j,n} \lfloor \frac{x}{j (n^2-j)} \rfloor$ with easily found asymptotic. As it is there is no reason to expect the density of integers with at least one pair of divisors will lead to something interesting. The OP didn't even compute some bounds for $\lim f(n)/n$ telling if $\gamma$ is plausible.

Comment: @KeithBackman:  a glitch in your formula is $j=2,n=2,k=1$ which gives $4$, which has no square among the sums of its divisors.  I think this will also apply to at least some $n=2p, j=2p^2, k=1$ for $p$ prime.  In that case we have $j=n^2-j$ and there may be only one of the two factors to sum to $n^2$.  I think specifying that $j \lt n^2/2$ is enough to cure that.

Comment: @KeithBackman:  another is when $j$ and $n^2-j$ share a common factor.  It misses $34$ because $2$ and $34$ are both factors, but $2\cdot 34$ is not.

Comment: @Ross Millikan Good catches. I should have been more careful and realized that the formula is only frequently true, not exhaustive.